# Sql query to find difference between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build query to find the difference between 2 tables and then update the table(domain) if there is difference. Example :

Table 1:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | sale |
| cde_t | test | supply |

Table 2:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | finance |
| cde_t | test | manufacture |

First scenario is to find out the records where table 1.schema=table 2.schema and table 1.table=table 2.table and table 1.domain!=table 2.domain.In table 1 for second record domain is supply and in table 2 its manufacturing the code value of supply is also manufacturing hence these 2 records are same. I have the code values available for domain but not sure while matching these 2 tables how do I convert it and match it based on domain.

second scenario is for the first record in table 1 is having domain as sale and second is having domain as finance hence need to update the table 2 record with domain as sale as table 1 domain will take priority.

I have tried to create query for both scenarios but for conversion not sure how to compare like how to compare supply with manufacturing though they are same only as code value of supply is manufacture so there is no change required for second record :

scenario1:

```
Select t1.schema,t1.table,t1.domain
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 
   on t1.schema=t2.schema
  and t1.table=t2.table 
  and t1.domain!=t2.domain
```

scenario2:

```
update table2 t2 set domain=colasce(t1.domain,t2.domain)
 where t1.schema=t2.schema and 
       t1.table=t2.table
       and t1.domain!=t2.domain
```

Ouptut:

| schema | table | domain |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc_t | sample | sale |
| cde_t | test | manufacture |

Comment: use `join` and `not` on the `on` clause?

Comment: @BagusTesa- Thanks for the reply, I am new in sql..hence need help to understand how can i build the better query to fulfill the above scenarios.

Comment: Your question and sample is incomplete IMHO. When they are "different" you are getting the value from table1, but when they are not (code value as you say, but didn't include sample for its table), then you are getting from table2. Also it is unclear what happens, when there are more than one match in either table.  (And if code values decide that they are same, then why don't you use code value and not a string).

Answer (score 0):

You can differentiate with a CASE WHEN if the t1.domain is sale

and then update it

```
UPDATE table2 AS t2 
SET t2.domain = CASE WHEN t1.domain = 'sale' THEn t1.domain ELSR t2.domain END 
FROM table1 AS t1
WHERE t1.schema=t2.schema and 
       t1.table=t2.table
       and t1.domain!=t2.domain
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q20DK3ME)

Comment: @nbk-Thank you,can you please help with scenario 1...how to find out the mismatch of records.

Comment: as you have only suplply and sale the code works, but you can expand the CASE WHEN if you beed more criteria